# ec2 instance high cpu consumption for a simple loop program

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have just try to run a python code on aws ec2 t2.medium instance , it has a 2 vcpu and 4 giB memory.

the program was simple   while True: print("hello"),  for the such simple program my cpu consumption is greather than 20%.

Actually i have to run program with some while True loop, before that i was testing the instance, how this can and is this have any solution

Comment: What are you comparing this with and what are your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your EC2 instance ran no code at all, there would still be some CPU usage seen on the console because the operating system and some AWS code will still use some CPU.

But what you're doing is a bit silly. Running a 'while true' loop with 'print("hello")' is going to being outputting "hello" as fast as it can. 20% CPU usage implies that the OS is only running your program 20% of the time of the total possible CPU scheduling time. It is likely that either (a) the OS is not scheduling the program to run more often than that, and/or (b) the program is I/O constrained which means it is spending most of the time waiting for the terminal buffer to print the word "hello" instead of running your while True loop.

"how this can and is this have any solution" -> the system is working as intended.

Comment: This. Also, I am curious if redirecting the output to `> /dev/zero` would increase the CPU usage in a significant way.